# I am getting the following error with the following code, how to fix?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an application in MVC4. My model is as follows:

```
public class NonComplianceData
{
   public static List<MonthDefinitions> Months = new List<MonthDefinitions>()
   {
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "January", Order = 1},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "February", Order = 2},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "March", Order = 3},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "April", Order = 4},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "May", Order = 5},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "June", Order = 6},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "July", Order = 7},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "August", Order = 8},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "September", Order = 9},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "October", Order = 10},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "November", Order = 11},
      new MonthDefinitions {Month = "December", Order = 12},
   };

   public int InspectorId { get; set; }
   public string InspectorName { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<MonthData> FullYearData { get; set; }
}

public class MonthDefinitions
{
   public string Month { get; set; }
   public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class MonthData
{
   public string Month { get; set; }
   public int TotalAuditsCompleted { get; set; }
   public int TotalNoDefects { get; set; }
   public decimal NonComplianceRate
   {
      get
      {
         if (TotalAuditsCompleted == 0)
         {
            return 0;
         }
         else
         {
            return (TotalNoDefects / (decimal)TotalAuditsCompleted) * 100;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to fill the data with the following:

```
var inspectorData = 
    context.COESDetails
           .Where(x => 
                x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId &&
                x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth.Contains(criteria.AuditYear))
           .Select(x => x.Inspector)
           .Where(y => y.Id != 0)
           .Distinct()
           .OrderBy(x => x.Firstname)
           .Select(ud => new NonComplianceData
                         {
                             InspectorId = ud.Id,
                             InspectorName = ud.Firstname + " " + ud.Surname,
                             FullYearData = 
                                NonComplianceData.Months.Select(month => 
                                         new MonthData
                                         {
                                             Month = month.Month,
                                         })
                          });
```

and I get the following error

> base {System.SystemException} = {"Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'AIS.Domain.Models.MonthDefinitions'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context."}

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks

**Additional notes:**

The problem is fixed if I use this

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Months = 
    new string[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
                    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
```

but I need to ensure that the months are sorted properly, that's why I added an order property

Comment: Where does this error occur?

Comment: Just to know, why dont you use enumerator instead of create your list? Edit : your List<MonthDefinitions> Months is basically an enumerator, why are you creating it?

Comment: Simon Whitehead - the error occurs in the inspectorData

Comment: Vinicius - please explain what you mean

Comment: Call `ToList` before your last `Select`. The problem is that whatever ORM you're using (probably Entity Framework?) cannot convert your complex object (`Months`) to a query.

Comment: SImon Whitehead - when I Call toList I get the following error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AIS.Domain.Models.MonthData] ToList[MonthData](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AIS.Domain.Models.MonthData])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Vinicius - I need to loop through the months and ensure that is ordered properly

Comment: You could try to work with KeyValuePair instead of creating a new class. It does the same and is native to System.Collections.Generic. How does that sound? A good example of how to use can be found here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/keyvaluepair

Comment: Simon Whitehead - you should put this as the answer.  I had to put a tolist() in my first select.  Thanks mate.. much apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

Given your error message:

> {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'AIS.Domain.Models.MonthDefinitions'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}

I would said that you should add `toList()` in your select clause since the ORM you're using (probably Entity Framework?) cannot convert your complex object `Months` to a correct query.