# How to fix the following code so that it is ordered?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an application with MVC 4.  The code requires that it goes and gets data for individuals for each month.  I have written the code so that it does that.
But the month is not ordered.  The final results shows the months are all over the place.
I want the months in its proper order January, February....

My model is as follows,

```
public class NonComplianceData
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> Months = new string[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
        public int InspectorId { get; set; }
        public string InspectorName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MonthData> FullYearData { get; set; }
    }

    public class MonthData
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }      
        public int TotalAuditsCompleted { get; set; }
        public int TotalNoDefects { get; set; }
        public decimal NonComplianceRate
        {
            get
            {
                if (TotalAuditsCompleted == 0)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return (TotalNoDefects / (decimal)TotalAuditsCompleted) * 100;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Then the code that fills the data is

```
var inspectorData = context.COESDetails
    .Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId 
        && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth.Contains(criteria.AuditYear))
    .Select(x => x.Inspector)
    .Where(y => y.Id != 0)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Firstname)
                    .Select(ud =>
                    new NonComplianceData
                    {
                        InspectorId = ud.Id,
                        InspectorName = ud.Firstname + " " + ud.Surname,
                        FullYearData = NonComplianceData.Months.Select(month => new MonthData
                        {
                            Month = month,
                            TotalAuditsCompleted = context.COESDetails.Count(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == (month + " " + criteria.AuditYear) && x.InspectorId == ud.Id && x.AuditType != (int)AuditType.NotSelected),
                            TotalNoDefects = context.COESDetails.Count(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth == (month + " " + criteria.AuditYear) && x.InspectorId == ud.Id && x.AuditType != (int)AuditType.NotSelected && x.COESDetailsCOESDefects.Any())
                        })

                    });
```

so how can I order by month?

I initially thought maybe I have a model like the following

```
 public class MonthDefinitions
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }


    }
```

but then I ran into other issues...

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the name to order by, and not the value in which they are.

So what you'll get is :

>
April 
August 
December 
February 
January 
July 
June 
March 
May 
November 
October 
September

You could either use the array position, or as you suggested, attach a numeric value to each month, and sort by that.

---

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258828/1698987), but basically, using something like:
`DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month`

---

Given:

```
IEnumerable<string> Months = new string[] 
{ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
  "November", "December" };
```

You want:

```
var sorted_months = 
    Months.OrderBy(m => DateTime.ParseExact(m, "MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ))
```

That will give you the months in their correct order

Comment: how do I use the array position to sort the linq I have got? can you show me how to do this please? when I tried to attach a numeric value to each month I got the following error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507937/i-am-getting-the-following-error-with-the-following-code-how-to-fix

Comment: no good, I am getting the following error base {System.SystemException} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: seems like you'll have to be more specific or try another thing.

Answer (score 1):

One of the guys at my work explained this to me..
he said leave it as

```
IEnumerable<string> Months = new string[] 
{ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
  "November", "December" };
```

When an array is defined, then it is used as shown.  By default no sort is applied, it will be used as it is defined.

However in my code when I was prefilling the data, because I was using Entity frame work, when it was being passed to sql it was doing a sort.  So he suggested that I put a toList at the end of my sql call

```
var inspectorData = context.COESDetails
    .Where(x => x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditZoneId == criteria.AuditZoneId 
        && x.UploadCOESDetails.AuditMonth.Contains(criteria.AuditYear)).ToList()....rest of the code
```

This kept the months in the order I defined them

Thanks for your help guys